# Join a wifi network only on macOS but not iOS

Tags: macos, ios, wifi

I have a WiFi network that I want to use from my macOS device (Sierra 10.12 / 2012 Macbook Pro), but not from my iOS device (iOS 10.2 / iPhone 7). The two devices use the same iCloud Keychain.

When I join from my macOS device, the iOS device joins the network as well. When I "forget this network" from the iOS device, the macOS device leaves as well.

Is there a way to decouple this? It's a corporate network, and I don't want to use it on my phone.

Comment: Seems like the same question as http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112729/selectively-disable-icloud-keychain-syncing-for-wifi-passwords