# How to disable wifi password sharing on iOS 11?

Tags: ios

Each time I unlock my iPhone, iOS 11 reminds me to share my wifi password, which is boring.

[image]

I've tried this [accepted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112738) answer, which does not work.

It is not feasible to power off someone else's device. Is there a setting on my own device to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because someone, that also is in your contact list, tries to enter a password for the WiFi network your device is connected to. If possible, find the MacBook Pro it wants to share the WiFi code with, and check if the MacBook is trying to connect to the WiFi network. If it is, power the MacBook off or type in the WiFi password on the MacBook.

Let me know if you have any questions or if it worked :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not feasible to power off someone else's device. Is there a setting on my own device to disable this feature?

Comment: No unfortunately you can't turn off this feature. But the message only appears if someone is trying to connect to your WiFi network, so if possible, ask the person who owns the MacBook to stop try connect the MacBook.You can also try to remove the person from your contact list if it doesn't bother you. Also i you can try to turn off Bluetooth.